# how to join on the values returned from Json_array_elements in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Structure of "Order" table:

```
objectId text, 
subOrders jsonb
```

structure of Jsonb: array of jsonb objects. eg.

```
[
   {
      "className":"SubOrder",
      "__type":"Pointer",
      "objectId":"tIENf1PCHO"
   },
   {
      "className":"SubOrder",
      "__type":"Pointer",
      "objectId":"yKVDFEuWx7"
   }
]
```

Structure of "SubOrder" table:

```
objectId text,
orderitems jsonb
```

structure of suborder.orderitems jsonb, eg:

```
[
   {
      "className":"SubOrderItem",
      "__type":"Pointer",
      "objectId":"6d1DLrmOTD"
   },
   {
      "className":"SubOrderItem",
      "__type":"Pointer",
      "objectId":"xK6mR2PDDU"
   }
]
```

I need to join `Order.suborders.objectId` with `suborder.objectid`

AS Order.suborders column is a jsonb array of objects, I am taking the array elements as below.

```
select jsonb_array_elements("subOrders")->>'objectId' 
from "Order"
```

Then is the problem to join the returned objectId with the Suborder table.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name thanks for editing the question.  Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the function call into the `FROM` clause and de-reference the actual field of the JSON object later.

```
select o.object_id, so.*
from "Order" o
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(sub_orders) j(suborder)
  join sub_order so on so.object_id = j.suborder ->> 'objectId'
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/GQBF88668

Comment: my query is like thisselect o.*, j.*, ot.*
from "Order" o
  cross join lateral select jsonb_array_elements("subOrders")->>'objectId' as j(object_id) from "Order"
  join "SubOrder" ot on ot."objectId" = j.object_id; and my error is syntax error at or near "->>"
LINE 3: ...oss join lateral jsonb_array_elements("subOrders")->>'object...  Please help

Comment: all my objectid are text fields only.

Comment: select o.*, j.*, ot.*
from "Order" o
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(o."subOrders")->>'objectId' as j("object_id")
 join "SubOrder" ot on ot."objectId" = j."object_id";... sorry that one is not correct. even with this there is same error.'

Comment: Edited my question with the structure of the tables involved and the requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Thank a lot.

Comment: Is the `lateral` required?

Answer (score 2):

I would use [WITH Queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html)

```
WITH suborders_object AS(
select jsonb_array_elements("subOrders")->>'objectId' AS obid from Order
)
SELECT * FROM suborders_object JOIN Order ON (suborders_object.obid = Order.id);
```

or any way you like to join suborders_object as like a table.

Comment: Thanks much Ashraful. can you also share the other method like joining with other table pls?

Comment: What about **[PostgreSql : Json Array to Rows using Lateral Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61709474/postgresql-json-array-to-rows-using-lateral-join)**?